# Create class for reading files

Tags: android, file, class, readline, android-context

I'm trying to create my own class for reading lines from a file, but that seems to be the problem.

From what I've been able to determine standard (Java) ways don't work under Android. I need to getResources() and so on.

```
public myInput(Context context) throws FileNotFoundException{
    super();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().
            openRawResource(R.raw.file)));
}
```

That's the constructor. I'm trying to create it like this.

```
public void choosePassword(Context context){
    try{
        myInput fromFile = new myInput(context);
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

The metod choosePassoword() is being called form my Activity class and to be honest don't know what he wants for Context. I want to give the method choosePassword() the file from which he should choose that password, that's what I want... can someone help me do just that?

Answer (score 2):

An `Activity` is an indirect sub-class of `Context` so you can simply use `choosePassword(this)` when calling it from your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... to be honest don't know what he wants for Context

OK. This is an important thing to understand in Android. Contexts are the basis by which almost all apps interact or even have an identity. A Context essentially identifies where a Component's run instruction originated (this is an oversimplification). For an Android Component to run, it must have a Context to run in. Luckily, in most circumstances, the Context is provided for you. There are two  specific types of Contexts that you will almost always have access to:

1. Every Activity is a Context. This one is subject to Lifecycle method calls.
2. Every Application is a Context. This one is outside of the Lifecycle and is initialized before any other Component of the Application is even created.

Both of these may be used whereever you may need a Context. If you need the Application Context, you may get it from nearly any component with the `getApplication()` method.

**For Your Purposes**

This makes your calls quite easy. If all of the calls are made from your Activity, then you may supply `this` as your argument. Even better, if the methods themselves are part of your Activity, you need not necessarily pass the Context as an argument and again, simply use `this`.

**Of Important Note**

You will learn that sometimes, it is easier to get one Context or another. You will also learn that sometimes while it may be more difficult, it is safer to use one Context over the other. For this, I would recommend reading up on the Lifecycle of an Activity. Not using the right one can result in memory leaks and unsafe execution. In general, if you need a Context for data or execution that only survives the Lifecycle, you can use an Activity. If you need a Context for data or execution that occurs outside the Lifecycle, use the Application.

Anyhow, didn't mean to write a book. There is a wealth of information on Contexts, how to use them and which to use. Certainly read up on it. It will make your life a **ton** easier.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks that helped. I've been trying to read up on it. But your crash course was spot on. Anyways.. thanks a mill.

Comment: No problem. That's part of what this site is about.